# How can I get a list of mounted drives with PHP?

Tags: php, macos

I'm writing a PHP/JavaScript web app that will run locally on OS X (e.g. localhost/myApp).

Is there a way to get a list of the names of all mounted drives on the server (which is essentially the local machine that the web app is running on) including attached USB drives and network shares?

Essentially I'm trying to implement a file browser for the server in PHP.

Comment: Wonder why this was modded down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use System_Mount package which allows you to mount and unmount filesystems and partitions listed in a system's `/etc/fstab`.

For example:

```
<?php
require_once 'System/Mount.php';

// Create the mount class
$m = new System_Mount();

// Get an object representing the CD-ROM entry
$cdrom = $m->getEntryForPath('/media/cdrom0');
```

However if there is any method in that class to list all mounted drives, I'm not sure, so you've to dig it out.

Install by: `pear install System_Mount`

---

Alternatively you'd have to parse some certain system commands, for example:

```
$ php -r "system('mount');"
$ php -r "system('diskutil list');"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try running the following PHP code:

```
 $output = array();
 exec("df -h", $output);
```

Now your variable output will contain various lines of output from the df command, which should list all mounted devices and some stats.